# ShinyApp R get rid of whitespace with SidebarPanel

Tags: r, markdown, whitespace, shiny

I've created simple ShinyApp using Markdown in R.

The point is to open app in full-sized window.

Here's code:
ui:

```
    library(shiny)
library(pdfetch)
library(quantmod)
quotes <- c(
"3M Company"="MMM",
"American Express Company"="AXP",
"Apple Inc."="AAPL",
"Caterpillar Inc."="CAT",
"Chevron Corporation"="CVX",
"Cisco Systems, Inc."="CSCO",
"Exxon Mobil Corporation"="XOM",
"General Electric Company"="GE",
"Intel Corporation"="INTC",
"International Business Machines Corporation"="IBM",
"Johnson & Johnson"="JNJ",
"JPMorgan Chase & Co."="JPM",
"McDonald's Corporation"="MCD",
"Merck & Co., Inc."="MRK",
"Microsoft Corporation"="MSFT",
"NIKE, Inc."="NKE",
"Pfizer Inc."="PFE",
"The Boeing Company"="BA",
"The Coca-Cola Company"="KO",
"The Goldman Sachs Group, Inc."="GS",
"The Home Depot, Inc."="HD",
"The Procter & Gamble Company"="PG",
"The Travelers Companies, Inc."="TRV",
"The Walt Disney Company"="DIS",
"United Technologies Corporation"="UTX",
"UnitedHealth Group Incorporated"="UNH",
"Verizon Communications Inc."="VZ",
"Visa Inc."="V",
"Wal-Mart Stores, Inc."="WMT")

ui<- 

  pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Porownanie prognozy metoda regresji oraz symulacji"),
  sidebarPanel(tags$hr(style="border-color: gray;"),

      br(),

      selectInput(inputId = "symb",label = "Wybierz akcje", choices = quotes),

dateInput(inputId = "data",label = "Wybierz date poczatkowa", min = "1900-01-01",max = Sys.Date(),
               startview = "decade", value = Sys.Date()-365, 
               language = "pl"),


 br(),
br(),
    actionButton("Pobierz", label = "Pobierz dane",icon = icon("download")),
    br(),
    br(),

br(),
br(),

tags$hr(style="border-color: gray;"),


sliderInput(inputId = "dni",label = "Liczba dni prognozy", min=1,max=365,value=30,step=1),
sliderInput(inputId = "symulacje",label = "Liczba sumulacji", min=1,max=1000,value=100,step=1),
align = "center",

 br(),
br(),
actionButton(inputId = "analiza",label = "Analizuj",icon = icon("calculator")),

br(),
br()
  ),
# Show a tabset that includes a plot, summary, and table view
# of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("DaneHistoryczne",
              plotOutput("Historia"),
              dataTableOutput("DaneHistoria"),
              icon = icon("database")),
      tabPanel("Analiza regresji",
              plotOutput("regression_plot"),
              dataTableOutput("finance_statement"),
              icon = icon("line-chart")),
      tabPanel("Symulacja Monte Carlo",
              h5("May take a couple seconds to load."),
              plotOutput("regression_plot2"),
              icon = icon("random")),
      tabPanel("Podsumowanie",
              plotOutput("regression_plot3"),
              dataTableOutput("finance_statement3"),
              icon = icon("file-text"))
    )
  )
)
```

and server:

```
# Define server logic for random distribution application
server<-function(input, output) {
# acquiring data

dataInput <- reactive({
if (input$Pobierz == 0)
return(isolate({
      pdfetch_YAHOO("MMM",from = as.Date(input$data),to=Sys.Date())
    }))
return(isolate({
      pdfetch_YAHOO(input$symb,from = as.Date(input$data),to=Sys.Date())
    }))
  })
datesInput <- reactive({
if (input$Pobierz == 0)
return(NULL)
return(isolate({
      paste0(input$data, "::",  Sys.Date())
    }))
  })


output$Historia <- renderPlot({
    chartSeries(dataInput(),
name = input$symb,
subset = datesInput(),
theme = "white")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui,server, options = list(height=980,width = 1100))
```

and the result I get is:
[Whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC3Dz.png)

I need to fit window or at least get rid of the whitespace on the left side.
I tried with FluidPage, FillPage, changing widths and heights. Nothing works.

Comment: It is usually easiest to just dink with the CSS to get the layout you want.

Comment: If you post a minimum working example I will gladly demonstrate a solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean as this is my first app. Code is included above, and it works.

Comment: I tried your code and I can not recreate your picture.  What web browser are you using?  A good minimal example is just that minimal.  Just what is needed to show the error.  There is a lot of other stuff going on there.

Comment: I'm using Safari. Does code work for you in anyway?

Comment: The code works, but it looks fine.  Unfortunately I do not have Safari, so I cant be of much help. However you can use CSS to position the elements however you want. My guess is there is a CSS property that is not set appropriately for Safari, so you will need to set it in your app.